# Import Native JavaScript file into Vue Component - Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created frontend application with Vue Js. I want to integrate one native javascript file into the Vue component.

The native js file contains multiple util functions. I want to call those functions from my Vue component.

Native js file util.js

```
var helper = function(t) {
                var u = 'product',
                    A = 'version',
                return {
                    buildHelpUrl: function(a, b, c) {
                                   return "http://"
                                 }
               /* Snippets */
             }
```

I tried following way to import in my native js file into .vue file

```
Case 1: import OTHHUrlBuilder from '@/util.js';
Case 2: import * as urlbulider from '@/util.js';
```

Nothing worked. Please help me to properly import and use the functions available in the native js files.

Comment: Are you exporting the helper  function from util.js file?

Comment: You can't import anything from non-modular JS. You need to make it a module first.

Answer (score 1):

**First export all your functions you need to your .vue file.**

Exemple on your .js file :

```
  const funcAdd = (a, b) =>  {
   return (a + b)
  }

  const funcSub = (a, b) =>  {
    return (a - b)
  }

  export { funcAdd , funcSub }
```

And then on your .vue file you can import all the exported functions.

On your .vue file :

```
  <script>

  import { funcAdd , funcSub } from '@/util.js'

 ...
```

**If you have only one function function, you can use** `export default`

On your .js file

```
const helper = (t) => {
          var u = 'product',
                    A = 'version',
                return {
                    buildHelpUrl: function(a, b, c) {
                                   return "http://"
                                 }
               /* Snippets */
             }

    export default helper
```

and on your .vue file

```
    import helper from '@/util.js'
```

Comment: It works fine as expected. One more scenario, Suppose inside the function *funcAdd* which also uses another js file function means where I need to import that js file

Comment: If you want to use a function that is in one .js file in another .js file, you can do the same process, take a look at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tck1ib?file=src%2FApp.vue).   Here is the code `import isANumber from './tools/isANumber';

const funcAdd = (a, b) => {
  if (isANumber(a) && isANumber(b)) {
    return a + b;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export { funcAdd };`